# Use existing 3-way switched receptacle to toggle power to a timed pump

Tags: electrical, wiring, pump, electronics

I have an existing 15 amp hot-water recirculation pump that's powered by a 3-way switched receptacle. Toggling one of the two 3-way switches either turns on or off the pump.

My goal is to be able to replace each of the two 3-way switches with momentary toggle switches that would cause the pump to turn on for fixed amount of time (say, 2 minutes) and then power off automatically.

1. Is it possible to repurpose the existing 3-way wiring for this purpose?
2. What kind of timer is required at the pump end of the circuit?

Comment: Just to be clear,  you want two timed 3 way switches, that triger the timer when powered

Comment: I take it you only want one preset amount of time, or do you want to be able to change the amount of time the pump runs for?

Comment: @Ruskes: I could see either two timed 3-way switches, or two momentary-toggle switches, each which trigger the pump for a preset amount of time.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: either a preset or variable amount of time is fine. I anticipate that it would always take the same amount of time to push hot water through the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would wire it like this.
[image]
Then each of the 3 way can trigger the timer.

Any countdown timer will do.
When the time is up the timer will rest and wait for next signal to start.

Alternative method without 3 way switches.

Install one of those in each location you want.
[image]

Then where ever you are just push the desired time. Connect the output wires togeter at the pump.

As per your request, here is full wiring for 2 timers replacing the 3 way switches.

[image: 2 timers]

Disconnect the 3 way switches

1- Find the incoming power cable, using a phase tester.

2- Disconnect it from 3 way switch and connect to timer 1

3- You have to bring the Power wire to the second Timer. Use the 3 way switch wire marked A. You will find it on the second 3 way switch by using a phase tester.

4- Use the wire from 3 way switch marked B and connect to Timer 1 output.

Connect all neutrals and grounds accordingly

Comment: The alternative option with two timer switches seems most flexible. Can you please describe how to adapt the 3-way wiring?

Comment: @Michael I can do that if you provide me with picture of the 2 boxes, so I can see the wires and the colors. Also identify which one is the incoming hot, simply with phase tester and it is not switchable.

Comment: Your diagram makes sense as is. No need to revise it with different colors. Many thanks!